# How to disable the parent check box if all other checkbox in the repeater is disabled using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

May be i am dumb or new to this please give me a solution .I have a repeater in which i am disabling the repeater check boxes from code behind by checking a condition in the item data bound .So if all the check box is disabled i want the main header check box also disabled .

I tried this but failed

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        if ($('#All input:checkbox').attr('disabled')) {
            $('#SelectAll').attr("disabled", true);
        }
            });
```

If all check box in the div #ALL disabled i want the check box "SelectAll" disabled

```
<asp:Repeater ID="AutoPublishList" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <td id="RemoveHead" runat="server">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="SelectAll" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="sortableHeaderSmall" onclick=" Sort('ProductName');">
                            Manager/Product
                        </td>
                        <td class="sortableHeaderSmall" onclick="Sort('PageID');">
                            Page
                        </td>
                        <td class="sortableHeaderSmall" onclick="Sort('IsPreliminary');">
                            Prelim
                        </td>
                        <td class="sortableHeaderSmall" onclick="Sort('LastSaved');">
                            Last Updated
                        </td>
                        <td class="sortableHeaderSmall" onclick="Sort('PublishDate');">
                            Time Published
                        </td>
                        <td class="sortableHeaderSmall" onclick="Sort('ErrorDisplay');">
                            Errors
                        </td>
                        <td class="sortableHeaderSmall" onclick="Sort('Comment');">
                            Comments
                        </td>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="RemoveCell" runat="server" style="" class="sortableBodySmall">
                                <div id="All">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="SelectRow" runat="server" value=' <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProductID")%>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="pageIDHidden" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PageID")%>' />
                                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="FirmID" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FirmID")%>' />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortableBodySmall" align="left">
                                <a class="primaAnchor" href='<%# String.Format("/pg/imq/mf/index.aspx?fid={0}&pid={1}", Eval("FirmID"),Eval("ProductID")) %>'
                                    target="_blank">
                                    <asp:Literal EnableViewState="False" ID="ProductName" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ProductName")%>' />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortableBodySmall" align="left">
                                <a class="primaAnchor" href='<%# String.Format("/pg/imq/imqpage{0}.aspx?fid={1}&pid={2}",Eval("PageID"), Eval("FirmID"),Eval("ProductID")) %>'
                                    target="_blank">
                                    <asp:Literal EnableViewState="False" ID="PageName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PageName")%>' /></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortableBodySmall" align="center">
                                <asp:Literal EnableViewState="False" ID="IsPreliminary" runat="server" Text=' <%# IIf(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsPreliminary") = True, "P", "")%> ' />
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortableBodySmall" align="right" style="width: 105px">
                                <asp:Literal EnableViewState="False" ID="LastSaved" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LastSaved")%>' />
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortableBodySmall" align="right" style="width: 105px">
                                <asp:Literal EnableViewState="False" ID="PublishDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PublishDate")%>' />
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortableBodySmall" align="left" style="width: 105px">
                                <asp:Literal EnableViewState="False" ID="ErrorDisplay" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ErrorDisplay")%>' />
                            </td>
                            <td class="sortableBodySmall" align="left">
                                <asp:Literal EnableViewState="False" ID="Comment" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment")%>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Why don't you share the javascript code of what you already tried? This way, it just looks like you're looking for somebody to do your own work.

Comment: i already posted in the question above -check "I tried this but failed"       $(document).ready(function () {

        if ($('#All input:checkbox').attr('disabled')) {
            $('#SelectAll').attr("disabled", true);
        }
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    if ($('#All input:checkbox:enabled').length <= 0) {
        $('#SelectAll').prop("disabled", true);
    }
 });
```

**EDIT**

Here's the fiddle with all checkboxes disabled, so you can see the main one is disabled too
http://jsfiddle.net/6P3WB/

And here the same fiddle with just one checkbox enabled, so you can see the main one is enabled too :)
http://jsfiddle.net/6P3WB/1/

Comment: @robin-hi robin i want the main check box "selectall" to be disabled only if all check boxes in the div is disabled.If any one is enabled i want that main check box enabled

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, I set  an example, adapt your code to your situation

```
<div id="test">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk" disabled="disabled" /> 1
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk" disabled="disabled" /> 2
    <input type="checkbox" class="chk" disabled="disabled" /> 3
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('#test input.chk:disabled').length == $('#test input.chk').length) {
            $('#chkAll').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
</script>
```